# DSA - can $k$ be 1?

Tags: dsa

I'm learning DSA and I'm wondering if $k$ can be 1. I know that k has to be from $\mathbb{Z}_{q-1}$ but I don't know whether 1 is allowed (not talking about security concerns, purely educational). I know that h can't be 1, because $h^{(p-1)/q}>1$ but I don't know about $k$.

Comment: @kelalaka I tried it and R was the same as S. However, I was still able to sign the message and verify the signature. Is that a problem?

Comment: @kelalaka no, would that open some attack vectors?

Comment: Though in theory I think $k=1$ is allowed though it actually occuring has a really small probability of roughly $1/q$ (as has any other fixed value knowing which immediately breaks DSA fully).

Answer (score 2):

The $k$ is randomly chosen as nonce (number used once) from the range $[1,q\hbox{ - }1]$ according to [NIST FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf). As far as I've searched there is no reason not to use $k=1$. The probability of selection $k=1$ is  $1/q$ and that is actually is very small.

You should not re-use any $k$. That simply breaks it. A [linearly increased](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/7904/18298) $k$ is also insecure. More than those any small bias while selection the $k$ can be catastrophic. See;

- [How does the “biased-k attack” on (EC)DSA work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44644/18298)
- [What is TPMFail attack and what are the countermeasures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75769/18298)

Also, one should not reveal any $k$ used for a signature made public. That compromises the private key, just as re-using any $k$ for two signatures made public. As a consequence, one should not purposely use $k=1$, nor any other particular public value ( thanks to fgrieu).

One can also use a deterministic process to generate the $k$:

- [RFC-6979](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) *Deterministic Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and
  Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)* : talks about

> It is possible to turn DSA and ECDSA into deterministic schemes by
> using a deterministic process for generating the "random" value k.
> That process must fulfill some cryptographic characteristics in order
> to maintain the properties of verifiability and unforgeability
> expected from signature schemes; namely, for whoever does not know
> the signature private key, the mapping from input messages to the
> corresponding k values must be computationally indistinguishable from
> what a randomly and uniformly chosen function (from the set of
> messages to the set of possible k values) would return.